# Is Hardware JPEG Compression a feature of high-end-scanners only?

Tags: scanner

Please guide me about "Scanners hardware JPEG compression feature". This feature allows the scanner to send compressed JPEG pictures to the software, not BMP or TIFF images as ordinary scanners do.

This feature doesn't make sense when the scanner is locally connected to computer, but has great importance for networking.

Is this feature built into budget scanners, or is hardware JPEG a privilege of hi-end models only?

Comment: So basically a network scanner, or rather specifically with scan-to-email/FTP/CIFS?

Comment: We are going to use Citrix access techonology that allows to connect to remote computer with one special feature: Local printers and scanners would be transparently "moved" to computer you connect to. I don't know how Citrix implemented scanners-hardware-bridge, but I guess that hardware JPEG compression is the only way to minimize traffic between local computer and computer you access via Citrix

Answer (score 2):

For an introduction on various scan-to-file techniques Brother have a pretty good page with videos:

http://www.brother.com/learningcenter/scan/index.html

Looks like you can find the functionality for US$299:

http://www.brother-usa.com/MFC/modeldetail.aspx?PRODUCTID=MFC7860DW&tab=spec

Comment: Thank you, @Steve! But I guess it's software/driver feature.

Comment: @Andrew consider easiest scenario is scanning JPG or PDF direct to a folder on the users account on your file server, e.g. "Drop Box" like OSX.  Then no client software setup is required at all.

Comment: sorry, but this will not for work me. Please, see my comments about Citrix. We are going to use scanners transparently "as-is" without special efforts.